# How to set time to 00:00 in jquery datetimepicker version 1.3.3?

Tags: jquery, datetime

I am using jquery datetime picker version 1.3.3. Here is the plugin link:- http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Now, I want to set the time to '00:00' always. Let me explain my requirement by giving the code first:-

```
 $('input:text[id*="date"]').each(function(){
    $(this).datetimepicker({
        formatTime:'H:i:s',
        formatDate:'Y-m-d',
        dayOfWeekStart : 1,
        lang:'en',
        allowTimes:[
          '00:00:00'
         ],
        hour: 00,
        minute: 00 
        //disabledDates:['1986/01/08','1986/01/09','1986/01/10'],
        //startDate:  '<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>'
    });
});
```

So, now my datetimepicker comes like this:-

[image]
Only, `'00:00'` is listed in the `'Time Selector'` list.

But when I select any date from the calendar, the time gets entered as the current time from my system. This is the screnshot:-

[image]

After, I select the time from the `'Time Selector'` list on the left, my time sets to `'00:00'`. After that no matter how many times I select date, time always comes as `'00:00'`.
[image]

How can I set the time to `'00:00'` instead of current time even for the first time when I select the date?

Comment: try to use setHours(0,0,0,0)

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón, how to do that?

Comment: just when recived value from date picker, and before put into input